# Only default controller's index function is being loaded on nginx server

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx, controllers

I am stuck with this problem. I am working with codeigniter 3.

Only default controller's index function is being loaded. No other controller is working.

I searched a lot about this topic even on stackoverflow, but nothing worked for me.

I also tried to change the files name to lowercase and also changed url's accordingly but nothing is working.

I developed the website using xampp apache on my localhost. It was working perfectly on localhost.

I have placed the codeigniter files under /var/www/html directory.

What could be the reason? I have been trying to find a solution for 3 days.

Comment: When helping someone answer a question, everyone here has the additional challenge that we don't have your code and don't know what you tried. Can you share more details? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

May be it was the issue with your htaccess

Try With index.php in the url like

http://example.com/index.php/controller/function

Comment: That didn't worked. I removed the .htaccess file in the root directory of codeigniter